# Print int Array with Stream using Arrays.asList method

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8, stream

I'm learning Stream and I tried to print an int Array using asList Method found in the class Arrays , unfortunatly i'm getting a wrong result.

could someone explain to me why i'm getting this wrong result.

```
public class array {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*my way*/
    int [] array = new int[]{1,2,3,7,1};
    Arrays.asList(array).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println();

    /*the good way*/
    Arrays.stream(array).forEach(System.out::print);

    }
    
}
```

result :

> [I@3e3abc88
>
> 12371

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Arrays.asList(array) -> a List<int[]>

Arrays.asList(array).stream() -> Stream<int[]>
```

Thus each element in the Stream in `int[]`, not an `int`; so you are trying to print an array (`Object`); this will not work as you might expect.

In the second example:

```
Arrays.stream(array -> IntStream
```

thus this is working

Comment: could you please write the correct awnser using aslist to print the element of the array because i tried to delete stream but i'm still getting the toString representation of the object.

Comment: @zakzak `Arrays.asList(array).stream().forEach(anArray -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(anArray)));`

Comment: Or just `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));`